# How do you get normalized devices coordinates into Apple's Metal kernel functions?

Tags: ios, 3d, metal

I have a kernel function in Metal that I pass in a texture to so that I can perform some operations on the image. I'm passing in `uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]]` which gives me the pixel coordinates as integers.

To get a the normalized devices coordinates I can do some simple math on `gid.x` and `gid.y` along with my texture width and heigh. Is this the best way to do it? Better way?

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is a good one. If you don't want to query the texture dimensions inside the kernel function or create a buffer just to pass them in, you can use the `-[MTLComputeCommandEncoder setBytes:length:atIndex:]` method to bind the texture dimensions in a "temporary" buffer of sorts that is handled by Metal:

```
[computeEncoder setBytes:&dimensions length:sizeof(dimensions) atIndex:0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you right, and it is good way to use the same approach usually is applied in GLSL:

1. compute texel size

`float2 texSize = float2(1/outTexture.get_with(),1/outTexture.get_height());`

2. then use it to get normalized pixel position

`constexpr sampler s(address::clamp_to_edge, filter::linear, coord::normalized);`

```
//
//  something to do...
//
float4 color = inTexture.sample(s,float2(gid)*texSize);

//
// something todo with pixel
//

outTexture.write(color,gid);
```

Answer (score 1):

The method specified in the question works well. But for completion, an alternate way to read from textures using non-normalized (and/or normalized device coordinates) would be to use samplers.

Create a sampler:

```
id<MTLSamplerState> GetSamplerState()
{
    MTLSamplerDescriptor *desc = [[MTLSamplerDescriptor alloc] autorelease];
    desc.minFilter = MTLSamplerMinMagFilterNearest;
    desc.magFilter = MTLSamplerMinMagFilterNearest;
    desc.mipFilter = MTLSamplerMipFilterNotMipmapped;
    desc.maxAnisotropy = 1;
    desc.sAddressMode = MTLSamplerAddressModeClampToEdge;
    desc.tAddressMode = MTLSamplerAddressModeClampToEdge;
    desc.rAddressMode = MTLSamplerAddressModeClampToEdge;

    // The key point: specifies that the sampler reads non-normalized coordinates
    desc.normalizedCoordinates = NO;

    desc.lodMinClamp = 0.0f;
    desc.lodMaxClamp = FLT_MAX;

    id <MTLSamplerState> sampler_state = nil;
    sampler_state = [[device_ newSamplerStateWithDescriptor:desc] autorelease];

    // Release the descriptor
    desc = nil;

    return sampler_state;
}
```

And then attach it to your compute command encoder:

```
id <MTLComputeCommandEncoder> compute_encoder = [comand_buffer computeCommandEncoder];
id<MTLSamplerState> ss = GetSamplerState();

// Attach the sampler state to the encoder, say at sampler bind point 0
[compute_encoder setSamplerState:ss atIndex:0];

// And set your texture, say at texture bind point 0
[compute_encoder setTexture:my_texture atIndex:0];
```

Finally use it in the kernel:

```
// An example kernel that samples from a texture,
// writes one component of the sample into an output buffer
kernel void compute_main( 
                texture2d<uint, access::sample> tex_to_sample [[ texture(0) ]],
                sampler smp [[ sampler(0) ]],
                device uint *out [[buffer(0)]],
                uint2 tid [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{
    out[tid] = tex_to_sample.sample(smp, tid).x;
}
```

Using a sampler allows you to specify parameters for sampling (like filtering). You can also access the texture in different ways by using different samplers attached to the same kernel. Sampler also avoids having to pass and check for bounds on texture dimensions.

Note that the sampler can also be set up from within the compute kernel. Refer to Section 2.6 Samplers in the [Metal Shading Language Specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/metal-shading-language-specification.pdf)

Finally, one main difference between read function (using gid, as specified in the question) vs. sampling using a sampler is that read() takes integer coordinates, whereas sample() takes floating point coordinates. So integer coordinates passed into sample will get casted into equivalent floating-point.

Comment: You cannot use uint as a second argument to .sample()